# Twitter Bootstrap 3, vertically center content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I know this has been asked a thousand time but I can't find a way to make the text and image to be centered vertically.

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap 3 with dynamic content so therefor, I do not know the size on neither the text nor the image. Plus, I want it all to be responsive.

I've created a [bootply](http://bootply.com/94381) that summarize the kind of layout I'm trying to achieve. Basically, I want the text and image to be vertically centered. The text is not always bigger than the image.

Can someone help me out with this please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can use `display:inline-block` instead of `float` and `vertical-align:middle` with this CSS:

```
.col-lg-4, .col-lg-8 {
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin-right:-4px;
}
```

The demo **http://bootply.com/94402**

Comment: Thanks Danko, your solution is indeed working but I'm not a big fan of setting negative margins. I am not even sure where comes the -4. Anyway, thanks for your time! :)

Comment: Is to avoid the space between inline-block elements

Comment: But will it always be -4px? Where does this number comes from?

Comment: Well the inline-block elements interpret blank spaces in the html markup and left a little white space ... you can set your html all inline or get this solution see this fiddle to clarify the concept http://jsfiddle.net/3vCKP/4/ if you reduce the margin-negative then you see the space

Comment: Thanks for the info! That clarifies it all. :)

Comment: @JacquesBourque to make this more clear check this link i found http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Thanks @Danko, it does clarifies a but more your explanation. This also confirm to me that the -4px can be something else. I guess the -4px is for the normal text size so I should be good with it.

Comment: This solution doesn't work anymore. :(

Comment: Note that every column of the row must implement that class. If one of the column is not implementing it, it fails.

Answer (score 46):

**Option 1** is to use `display:table-cell`. You need to unfloat the Bootstrap col-* using `float:none`..

```
.center {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    float:none;
}
```

http://bootply.com/94394

---

**Option 2** is `display:flex` to vertical align the row with flexbox:

```
.row.center {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/7rAuLpMCwr

---

Vertical centering is very different in **Bootstrap 4**. See this answer for Bootstrap 4 https://stackoverflow.com/a/41464397/171456

Comment: Thanks Skelly! I tried a solution like yours before but I was missing 'float: none'. Plus, in my real project, I was setting 'hidden-xs' on the same '<div>' as the one defining the 'col-sm-x'. Works great now!

Comment: I just hit one small issue. I am loosing the img-responsive feature now. Is there a way to have both (responsive and centered)?

Comment: I'm gonna have to mark Danko's anwser as accepted since it fixes the vertical alignment and the responsive feature of the image. I guess the issue come from the fact that we change the 'display' on the row and/or the column.

Comment: remember the parent element must either have `display: table;` set or have a specific height set for this to work.

Comment: This solution breaks for me when columns wrap: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-wrapping.

Comment: Nice option 2 without overwriting the float attribute!