# Vertical alignment in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have following setup in Bootstrap 4: [Bootply link](http://www.bootply.com/xieEeaDl3p)

The element with the "Supplier" text in it should be vertically centered, I have different rows with the same code and I want them centered. No solution seems to work for me.

Can someone here find what I did wrong and point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Comment: I'd use [Bootstraps v4 flexbox grid version](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/flexbox-grid/) which has many features, like [vertical alignment](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/flexbox-grid/#vertical-alignment).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap Center Vertical and Horizontal Alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42388989/bootstrap-center-vertical-and-horizontal-alignment)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

<strike>You can use the `flex-xs-middle` class like this..</strike>

**Bootstrap 4 Alpha 5**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="circle-medium backgrounds"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 flex-xs-middle">
            <div class="name">Supplier</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="circle-medium backgrounds"></div>
        </div>
         <div class="col-xs-6 flex-xs-middle">
            <div class="name">Supplier</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/PNNaNCB4T5 (Using the Bootstrap 4 flexbox enabled CSS)

**Bootstrap 4**

---

**UPDATE for Bootstrap 4.0.0**

Now that Bootstrap 4 is **flexbox by default** there are many different approaches to vertical alignment using: [auto-margins](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/#auto-margins), [flexbox utils](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/), or the [display utils](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/display-property/) along with [vertical align utils](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/vertical-align/). At first "vertical align utils" seems obvious but these *only* work with inline and table display elements. Below are the Bootstrap 4 vertical centering options. **Remember, vertical alignment is relative to [parent height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049875).**

---

**1 - Vertical Center Using Auto Margins:**

Another way to vertically center is to use `my-auto`. This will center the element within it's container. For example, `h-100` makes the row full height, and `my-auto` will vertically center the `col-sm-12` column.

```
<div class="row h-100">
    <div class="col-sm-12 my-auto">
        <div class="card card-block w-25">Card</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Vertical Center Using Auto Margins **Demo**](http://www.codeply.com/go/akn5BYxQwn)

`my-auto` represents margins on the vertical y-axis and is equivalent to:

```
margin-top: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
```

---

**2 - Vertical Center with Flexbox:**

[image: vertical center grid columns]

Since Bootstrap 4 `.row` is now `display:flex` you can simply use `align-self-center` on any column to vertically center it...

```
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-6 align-self-center">
                <div class="card card-block">
                 Center
                </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-6">
                <div class="card card-inverse card-danger">
                    Taller
                </div>
          </div>
    </div>
```

or, use `align-items-center` on the entire `.row` to vertically center align all `col-*` in the row...

```
       <div class="row align-items-center">
           <div class="col-6">
                <div class="card card-block">
                 Center
                </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-6">
                <div class="card card-inverse card-danger">
                    Taller
                </div>
          </div>
    </div>
```

[Vertical Center Different Height Columns **Demo**](http://www.codeply.com/go/GFgGl4YS27)

***Important***: The [*direct* parent of the element to be aligned must have a defined *height*](https://www.codeply.com/go/PuecvHSh08)!

---

**3 - Vertical Center Using Display Utils:**

Bootstrap 4 has [display utils](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/display-property/) that can be used for `display:table`, `display:table-cell`, `display:inline`, etc.. These can be used with the [vertical alignment utils](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/vertical-align/) to align inline, inline-block or table cell elements.

```
<div class="row h-50">
    <div class="col-sm-12 h-100 d-table">
        <div class="card card-block d-table-cell align-middle">
            I am centered vertically
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Vertical Center Using Display Utils **Demo**](http://www.codeply.com/go/30DYTbq83o)

Comment: Now that Bootstrap has moved to Beta, can you rearrange the order of your answer such that the standard way appears first? you can still leave the code for bootstrap 4 alpha 5 below

Answer (score 3):

To have a **main element** on the page vertically centered using `.my-auto` class, applying full-height on every element before it is required; using one of the following:

- `.h-100` Bootstrap class
- `height: 100vh;` style
- `height: 100%;` style

Example:

```
<body class="h-100">
  <div class="container h-100">
    <div class="row h-100">
      <div class="col-12 my-auto"> <!-- Finally! -->
        <div class="jumbotron">
          ...
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```