# How do I position text on the bottom of an image overlay in a card in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4 and cards with image overlay to put some text over the image. The text appears on the top of the image, while I want it to be at the bottom.

This is the html code for the cards:

```
 <div class="card-deck">
      {% for article in article_list|slice:":3" %}
      <div class="card card-inverse align-self-center">
          <div class="card-header text-center">
            {{ article.category|capfirst }}
          </div>
        <img class="card-img" src="{% static article.image %}" alt="Card    image cap">
        <div class="card-img-overlay">
            <h4 class="card-title">{{ article.title }}</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: wrap your `.card-title` in a div and make it position absolute and position it to bottom

Answer (score 16):

Make the `card-img-overlay` display flex using `d-flex`, and then `justify-content-end` to align at the bottom..

```
       <div class="card bg-inverse">
              <div class="card-header text-center">
                    Category
              </div>
              <img class="card-img" src="//placehold.it/400" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-img-overlay h-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-end">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
              </div>
       </div>
```

**Demo:** https://www.codeply.com/go/7tnRTddIh6

More on [vertical align in Bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265182/vertical-alignment-in-bootstrap-4/41464397#41464397)

Comment: This only works right if the image is the bottom-most object in the card. If you put a body or footer below, the title shows up overlaying the bottom content.

Comment: That wasn't the scenario in question. The *overlay* is designed to overlay everything in the card. "Depending on the image, you may or may not need additional styles or utilities." __ the Bootstrap docs

Answer (score 1):

If you want to align overlay vertically the simplest solution is to add `d-flex` and `align-items-end` to `card-img-overlay`. This will move h3 to the bottom of the card

```
<div class="card bg-inverse">
   <div class="card-header text-center">
      Category
   </div>
   <img class="card-img" src="//placehold.it/400" alt="Card image cap">
   <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex align-items-end">
      <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
   </div>
</div>
```

If you want you can read more about aligning items vertically in bootstrap look here:

[Bootstrap 4 Align-items](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/#align-items)

On css-tricks.com you can find amazing guide how the flexbox behaves - check here:
[A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)