# How to place place set a text in the middle in a div with row class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to place the text at the same line as the pagination's buttons.
[image]

As you can see in the code below, I've tried putting the text into a `<span>` element, rising the height of the span, and/or using the setting the `vertical-align: middle;` with no luck.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" aria-label="Previous">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" aria-label="Next">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1" style ="vertical-align: middle;">
        <span style="height: 70px; display: block;">
            10 of 137 items
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Did you try any of these solutions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20005278/twitter-bootstrap-3-vertically-center-content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `valign` class to your row that makes it `flex` with `align-items: center` for vertical alignment.

```css
.valign {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row valign">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" aria-label="Previous">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" aria-label="Next">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <span>
            10 of 137 items
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;` if you don't mind getting your hands a little dirty.

```css
div[class*="col"] {
    width: 49%;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.col-md-1 span {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" aria-label="Previous">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" aria-label="Next">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1" style ="vertical-align: middle;">
        <span style="height: 70px;;">
            10 of 137 items
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

set line-height and height of span as same will vertically align the text

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" aria-label="Previous">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" aria-label="Next">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1" style ="vertical-align: middle;">
        <span style="height: 70px;line-height:70px; display: block;">
            10 of 137 items
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```